# Java Hibernate Error org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

Hello I have a problem with the execution of a Query inside Java using Hibernate.

When I use this Query:

```
        Query query = dbSession.createQuery("SELECT activitydate, userid, sum(time) as homeofficeTime FROM Hours AS hours " + 
               "WHERE (hours.comment ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%homeoffice%', '%home office%']) OR " +
                        "remark ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%homeoffice%', '%home office%'])) AND " +
                    "hours.activitydate BETWEEN :from AND :to " +
                        "AND userid = :user " +
                "GROUP BY activitydate, userid ORDER BY activitydate ");
        

        query.setLong("user", employee.getUserid());
        query.setCalendar("from", from);
        query.setCalendar("to", to);
```

I get this Error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ILIKE near line 1, column 129 [SELECT activitydate, userid, sum(time) as homeofficeTime FROM com.thiesen.timesheet.sql.dbo.Hours AS hours WHERE (hours.comment ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%homeoffice%', '%home office%']) OR remark ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['%homeoffice%', '%home office%'])) AND hours.activitydate BETWEEN :from AND :to AND userid = :user GROUP BY activitydate, userid ORDER BY activitydate ]
```

However when I use this Query:

```
        Query query = dbSession.createQuery("SELECT activitydate, userid, sum(time) as homeofficeTime FROM Hours AS hours " + 
                   "WHERE hours.comment = 'test Homeoffice tst' AND " +
                        "hours.activitydate BETWEEN :from AND :to " +
                            "AND userid = :user " +
                    "GROUP BY activitydate, userid ORDER BY activitydate ");

        query.setLong("user", employee.getUserid());
        query.setCalendar("from", from);
        query.setCalendar("to", to);
```

It works and I get a Result back: `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@7221ae50]`

Both of the Query work if I test them inside Adminer and run the Querys there but for some Reason the first one wont work in my Project. Does Hibernate not know what to do with "ILIKE" or "LIKE" or the "Array[]" Part?

Comment: `ìlike` is not sql standard, so jpql/hql can't handle it. `like` should work but without array

Comment: Okay I am connected to a postgresql DB which obviously knows ILIKE. However when I switch it to LIKE it still does not work - i tells me that the unexpected Token is ARRAY. Is there a workaround? Can I use LIKE with multiple ORs ?

Comment: Like can not be used with `ARRAY`. also `ARRAY` is not sql standard

Comment: @Jens Okay I think I can handle it with multiple LIKE statements.